# Show create content menu item to ananymous users but call URL for login/register popup on click

Tags: 7, routes, users, theming

I thought it would be simple to do, but after lots of searching I couldn't find exact solution for it.

So the issue is, I have 2-3 main menu items which I have to show to anonymous users but have to call a URL(for login/register popup) & prompt for login or register if they click on them.

Best solution I found for create content link **"node/add/node-type"** was something like --

```
function THEME_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
    global $user;
    # if url starts with "add" and current user is anonymous
    if (arg(1) === 'add' && $user->uid === 0) {
          # redirect to login page
          drupal_goto('user/login');
          exit;
    }
}
```

It didn't work & it says - "$base_path has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer."

This is a very important functionality thing & I don't know how people resolve it. Can I get any suggestion for it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [hook_node_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) for that.

Of course it's not a turn-key solution, but I'm sure this example will help anyone who will face this kind of issues.

Example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_node_access().
 */
function MYMODULE_node_access($node, $op, $account) {

  // define restricted node id's
  $restricted_nids = array(7,27);

  // If $node is a string, the node has not yet been created. We don't care
  // about that case.
  // Check permissions only for restricted nids.  
  if (!is_string($node) && in_array($node->nid, $restricted_nids) && $op == 'view') {

    global $user;

    // OPTION #1
    // Give an access if they have ANY of these roles.

    //$has_permission = array_intersect(array('testrole', 'testrole2'), array_values($user->roles));
    //return $has_permission ? NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW : NODE_ACCESS_DENY;

    // OPTION #2
    // Give an access if they have ALL of required roles.   

    $required_roles = array('testrole', 'testrole2');
    $has_permission = (count(array_intersect($user->roles, $required_roles)) == count($required_roles)) ? TRUE : FALSE;
    if ($has_permission) {
      return NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW;
    }
    else {
      if ($user->uid) {
        drupal_set_message("You don't have appropriate permission to view this content");
      }
      else {
        drupal_set_message('You have to login to see this content');
        drupal_goto('user/login'); 
      }
      return NODE_ACCESS_DENY;
    }
  }
  return NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and solved it without coding.

1. Manually set the menu path with absolute URL, ie. http://yourdomain.com/node/add/node-type
2. Install and enable the module r4032login‎
3. Done!