# How can I hide menu items based on permissions?

Tags: routes, users

In my main menu I have a "menu item 1" that links to mynode1.

I have successfully implemented `hook_permission()` and `hook_node_access()` so that users who do not have the "access menu item 1" permission  cannot access mynode1.

I assumed that the menu item link "menu item 1" would automatically be hidden by Drupal, but this is not the case. Therefore I now would like to hide that menu item to users who do not have "access menu item 1" permission.

Does anyone have a code sample that would hide a menu link based on permission? (I tried `hook_menu_alter()` with no luck.)

Comment: Its drupal default behaviour as I remember..

Comment: If you hide a link, it doesn't mean that user won't be able to visit that content. You need to use [hook_node_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7) and [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/80404/16739) you have a good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi have done it this way:

```
function mymodule_menu_link_alter(&$item) 
 {
  $item['options']['alter'] = TRUE;                                                                                                                                                      
 } 

function mymodule_translated_menu_link_alter(&$item, $map) 
 {

  if (!empty($item['access'])) {

  if(
   ( $item['link_title']=="MyLinkToHide1" && !user_access("access link 1") ) ||
   ( $item['link_title']=="MyLinkToHide2" && !user_access("access link 2") )

   )
   {
            $item['access'] = FALSE;
   }

 }
}
```

Comment: There actually is a better way [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52756/views-search-ignoring-custom-node-access-permissions?rq=1) : "It seems that a better way to control node access through hook_node_access_records and hook_node_grants as described [here](http://drupal.org/node/1260948)".

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to hide the menu items according to permissions is to use `hook_menu_link_alter` and set `$item['hidden'] = 1;` if `user_access` returns false.

**Resources**

1. [user_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.module/function/user_access/7)
2. [hook_menu_link_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu_link_alter/7)

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Menu item visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility) module.

> This module exposes configurable and extendable visibility settings
>   for menu links. For example, if you want to create a 'My account' link
>   that points to /user, both anonymous and registered users have access
>   to the /user path, so both will see the link, even if anonymous users
>   do not technically have an account. Using this module will allow you
>   to only have your 'My account' link visible to registered users, and
>   hide it from anonymous users.